# Data is getting added into spinner using arraylist instead of getting updated in addChildEventListener's onChildChanged()

Tags: android, arrays, firebase-realtime-database, android-spinner

how my firebase database looks:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPU8T.png)

here I have my data in which I added course name and semester number. My data is displayed in spinner but it added data with previous data which is already in spinner.
I want to update it according to a selection of items in spinner.

```java
listCourse.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String courseName = listCourse.getSelectedItem().toString();
            corsename.setText(courseName);
            String corseName = corsename.getText().toString();
            fDatabase.getReference("Engineer_Future").child("course_semester").child(corseName)
                    .child("Semesters").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                    int semesters = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
                    semesterList.add(semesters);
                    semesterAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(UploadFiles.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,semesterList);
                    semesterSpinner.setAdapter(semesterAdapter);


                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

please help me to do this task according to an item selected.

here is my app screenshots :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MffPf.jpg)

this is by default and I want like this type when selection changed. But the result is shown in below pic:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7RyA.jpg)

Comment: in onChildChanged method add semesterAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); and  read this [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events)

Comment: Not working I already did semesterAdapter.notifyDataSetChange() ;